# `filter.applyTo is not a function` error when try to change image src using setSrc() in fabric js

Tags: filter, fabricjs, src

Currently, I am Working on image editor that allows me to crop an image and apply a filter.
I am using fabric js version 1.7.22.
I want to implement crop functionality.
so my cropping  flow is like Below :

1. crop image using a plugin and ger base64 of the cropped image.
2. generate blobUrl from base64 which help to display image in fabric js canvas.
3. After Cropping the image, I Just replace old image src with new One.

It works fine when an image has no filter.

but when I try to set a filter in the image first then try to replace src using setSrc() function.

It throws an error like Below
    `filter.applyTo is not a function`

I have created one fiddle for demonstrating to replace src after the apply filter.
  https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/98gLhcb4/1/

And I Can't upgrade my fabric js version. If any patch Available then

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this piece of code:

```
canvas.getActiveObject().setSrc('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(){
  canvas.renderAll();
}, canvas.getActiveObject().toObject());
```

You're passing `canvas.getActiveObject().toObject()` as an `options` object, which is assigned to your image in `setSrc()` -> `setElement()` -> `_initConfig()`.

`toObject()` serializes your `fabric.Image`, and `filters` array no longer contains the actual `fabric.Filter`, but rather a serialized version of it. So, it does not have a prototype with `applyTo()` method on it, hence the error `filter.applyTo is not a function` when fabric tries to reapply filters to your image after `setSrc()`.

Instead of passing the whole serialized object as options, you'll need to pick the properties you actually want to be passed. As I'm not sure about what your requirements are, I tried replacing the above code with the following and it worked for me:

```
  var options = canvas.getActiveObject().toObject();
  delete options.filters;
  options.crossOrigin = true;
  canvas.getActiveObject().setSrc('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(){
    canvas.renderAll();
  }, options);
```

Note the `options.crossOrigin = true` - you won't be able to apply filters without it.